# Python: convert and join rows of a text file into a dictionary with list values

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a text file with an arbitrary (non-Python) list of blocks of four lines, as follows:

```
WHAT
EVER
0.00000904
17577

FOO
BAR
7.00000031
426
```

The file comprises thousands of such blocks. How can I convert the data in the file into a dictionary of lists, where the key is the first two lines of each block, concatenated, and the next two lines are the list values? For example:

```
{'WHATEVER': [0.00000904, 17577], 'FOOBAR': [7.00000031, 426]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import re

# Open the file
data = open('odd_lines.txt').read()

# Split on the double newline characters
data = data.split("\n\n")

# Split each element of the data list on the newline characters followed by a float
data = [re.split("\n(\d+\.\d+)", x) for x in data]

# Put the data in a dictionary with the key being the first element of each element of the data list.
# Make sure to replace the newline character with an empty space
output = {x[0].replace("\n",""):[float(y) for y in x[1:]] for x in data}

print(output)
```

This should yield:

```
#{'FOOBAR': [7.00000031, 426], 'WHATEVER': [0.00000904, 17577]}
```

The following is the starting file (`odd_lines.txt`):

```
WHAT
EVER
0.00000904
17577

FOO
BAR
7.00000031
426
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This works on the odd_lines.txt. However I am running into issues on the larger text file, each line formatted as its own dictionary; it looks like:

    {u'WHAT': []}
    {u'EVER': []}
    {u'0.00100001': []}
    {u'10101': []}
    {u'': []}
    {u'FOO': []}
    {u'BAR': []}
    {u'0.00500761': []}
    {u'7991282': []}
    {u'': []}

Comment: Please share a larger text file that you think could include cases where you are getting this unwanted outcome.

Comment: @skeletonsaurus, my hands are tied here because what you show as your starting point is working with the code I have provided here. Unless you change the starting file into something that is outputting the wrong solution, I really cannot do much.

Comment: This resolved the issue (since some of the WHAT's and EVER's started with numbers):
change the regex from 
data = [re.split("\n(?=[0-9])", x) for x in data]
to
data = [re.split("\n(?=[0-9]+$)", x) for x in data]

Comment: That won t work on python 3 because map doesnt return a list anymore. Use a listcomp instead.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I assume that he or she is using python 2 given that it's working. But you got a valid point.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
import os

# set base path to main dir of target file
root = os.getcwd()
# split on double spaces
vals = open(os.path.join(root, 'test.txt'), 'r').read().split('\n\n')

# create empty dictionary to store values
valdict = {}

# iterate over each item which should contain the keys and values
for val in vals:
    # fill in dict with key and turn numbers into float and dict value as float list
    key = ''.join(val.split('\n')[0:2])
    nums = val.split('\n')[2:]
    nums = map(float, nums)
    valdict[key] = nums

valdict
# output: {'FOOBAR': [7.00000031, 426.0], 'WHATEVER': [9.04e-06, 17577.0]}
```

Comment: I am encountering this issue when I run your solution:

File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    nums = map(float, nums)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: